# Google Chrome Privacy Error NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, https, clock

**Background:**

I'm running Windows 7 SP1. Using Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m.

For a while my computer's clock was set to sync with time-b.nist.gov automatically, but the correct time would never display. It would usually be 4 hours ahead. My time zone is set to Eastern time (UTC -5:00, East cost of USA), which is correct.

I had it set to sync time-b.nist.gov instead of time.windows.com because I would receive an error when trying to sync time.windows.com or most other options. Today I finally had some time to try and fix it. I started by selecting update time.windows.com and clicked update now.

I received an error, I'm not sure exactly what it said, something about the request timing out or taking too long to respond. I didn't make note of the error because it had set my time correctly after, so I saved the settings and closed the window.

**Problem:**

Later I tried to log into Facebook when Chrome threw up the NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error page. I'm now blocked from any site that uses https in Chrome. However, Firefox (what I'm using now) is working just fine.

**Solutions I've Tried:**
After some looking around I noticed the most common reason people get this error is because their system clock is set to the wrong date/time. However, mine is not, at least as far as I can tell. I have now way of telling if my computer has the correct minute/second. but the date and hour are correct.

I've tried syncing with different time servers to no avail.

I've tried restarting my computer and uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome, with no results.

All security scans come up clean.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, or even why my initial error happened. I'm even further confused as to why my system had the incorrect time but was still able to access https sites using Chrome.

If anyone has run into this issue before an can offer a solution, or even just put me down the right path, I would really appreciate it. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can you explain your downvotes please?

Answer (score 2):

- Try to set your date one day ahead of today.
- Close than open your browser again. Hope it would work.